# How to trigger an event after hitting Tab key in textbox

Tags: tabs, jquery

I want to trigger an event like displaying an alert message when I hit the `Tab` key inside a textbox.

```
<input type="text" />

$("input").blur(function (e) {
   if (e.which == 9)
       alert("Hurray!!!");
});
```

What I want to happen is that whenever I type inside a textbox then hit `Tab` it will do something.

Im using `jquery1.7.2.min.js`

I really don't know if Im doing it right.

For the demo http://jsfiddle.net/QfCpC/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$("input").keydown(function (e) {

   if (e.which == 9)
       alert("Hurray!!!");
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QfCpC/1/)**

Comment: I've had to use window.event.keyCode instead of e.which in some cases. It's browser-dependent.

Comment: Cool! If you are using AngularJS then you can do ng-keydown too :)

Answer (score 2):

Will this help

```
$("input").live("keydown" , function (e) {
if (e.which == 9)
   alert("Hurray!!!");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QfCpC/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" />

$("input").keydown(function (e) {
   if (e.which == 9)
        $('#someButton).trigger('click');//or you can directly call the handler also
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input").bind("keydown",function (e) {

   if (e.which == 9)        
       alert("Hurray!!!");
});
});
```

demo here..

http://jsfiddle.net/QfCpC/

Answer (score 1):

In order for the `e.which` parameter to be set properly, I believe it has to be called from a keydown event.

See the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/QfCpC/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try : **http://jsfiddle.net/cEzLL/**

```
$("input").keydown(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 9)
       alert("Hurray!!!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is when u hit 'tab' two actions takes place

1. KeyUp for tab button
2. Blur action for Input type field

Now according to your code you are adding eventlistner to blur event ... and blur event doesn't have property of giving you key binding.

So in order to do this you need to bind "keydown".

```
$("input").keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 9)
       alert("YEYYYYYYY!!!");
});
```