# JQuery: How to listen for multiple events and only fire one for each input text change in a form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, events

I have a form where i want to get each input text updated in the database when either the user types a new value or the user makes a change in the text.

To achieve this, i use three events: input, change, and focusout.

I have chosen input to detect when the user is selecting an input text and then check if the original text inside the input text has changed.

I use change to detect if the user has modified a date through the bootstrap-datepicker.js.

So here is the JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var timerid;
                $("input").on("input change",function(e){ //referencias: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2534107/1883256
                    //para ver que se active con el TAB, checar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889732/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-hitting-tab-key-in-textbox
                    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    //preguntar si el dato del input en donde está el cursor ha cambiado:
                    if($(this).data('lastval')!=value){
                        $(this).data('lastval',value);
                        nuevoValor=$(this).val();
                        clearTimeout(timerid);
                        timerid=setTimeout(function(){
                            var editform = $('#formedit2').serializeArray();
                            editform.push({name:'identifier',value:currentId});//http://stackoverflow.com/a/13362942/1883256
                            //agregando el ID a la serie de datos:
                            //alert(editform);
                            var url = $("#formedit2").attr('action');//con esto se llama al controlador correspondiente!
                            $('#'+currentId).addClass('loadinggif');
                            $.post(url, editform, function(data,status){
                                $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
                                //alert(data);
                                if(data=='fail'){
                                    alert('No se pudo actualizar el campo. Status:' + status);
                                    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
                                }else if(data=='success'){
                                    alert('Dato actualizado exitosamente! Status: ' + status);
                                    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
                                    $('#'+currentId).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success').addClass('has-feedback');
                                }else if(data=='timeout'){
                                    alert('El tiempo de espera se ha agotado. Recargue la página.');
                                    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
                                }else if(data=='error'){
                                    alert('Ha habido un error. Favor de intentar de nuevo más tarde. Data:'+data);
                                    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
                                    $('#'+currentId).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                                }
                                else if(data==400){
                                    alert('error! please check');
                                    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
                                    $('#'+currentId).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');                          
                                }else{
                                    $('#formedit2 input').removeClass('loadinggif');
                                    $('#'+currentId).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                                    alert('Unknown process. Status: '+status+'. Data: '+data);
                                }
                            });//fin de la función del post
                            //FIN DEL PROCEDIMIENTO DE ACTUALIZACIÓN DE LA INFO
                        },2500);//TIEMPO DE ESPERA PARA REALIZAR LOS CAMBIOS
                    };//fin del IF de si hubo cambios en el valor del Input
                });//fin de la parte del input          
        </script>
```

Until here is fine, since the script listens and waits for 2.5 seconds after the user has stopped typing to update the data in the database.

Now i want to listen for another event where the user types the TAB key in order to go on the next input text. For this, i use the focusout event.

So i added it to the following (focusout):

```
$("input").on("input change focusout",function(e)
```

My issue here is that if i type something and then i change fast to the next input by using the Tab key, the first column is checked whether it will be updated or not, and then i go to the next one and so on by using the Tab key again, i notice that not all changes of each input are updated but the first one.

I want the script to launch just one event. For example, if i type something and then i stop, after 2.5 the event's timer will lauch the updating process, but if i click on tab, the updating process must be triggered immediately and the rest of the process must be cancelled.

I see that all events are triggered, how do i do to make just one event handle the updating process?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood the question correctly but it seems like you might use some kind of a delay in your event handler and check if tab is pressed during that delay period. If so then you cancel handler execution. That way you can have TAB pressed as many times as you want but event will get handled only once the delay time expires after last TAB pressed.

Comment: Hello, @dee zg I want the tab to lauch the updating process immediately and cancel the other two events. I have tried this by separating on('focusout'),... and then on('type change')... but it doesn't work. Or how do i do to fire only one of the three events?